# Registering jquery radio button click event doesn't work

Tags: radio-button, jquery

I am trying to set a hidden form field with the value of a selected radio button. I have the following code:

```
    $(function () {
        // set hidden form field with selected timeslot
        $('input[name=["timeslot"]').live("click", (function () {
            var valu = $(this).val();
            alert(valu);
            $("#selectedSlot").val(valu);
        }));
    });
```

All radio buttons have the name "timeslot", and I would like to run this function whenever one is clicked. However, the alert box shows blank when I click one of the radio buttons.

UPDATE: Oops! Didn't see the double square brackets. However I fixed it:

```
        $('input[name="timeslot"]').live("click", (function () {
            var valu = $(this).val();
            alert(valu);
            $("#selectedSlot").val(valu);
        }));
```

and I am STILL having the same problem. In fact, the alert box does not even come up any more for some reason.

UPDATE 2: Actually, in my real code I have other events registered in my initiation block besides this one -- if I take out all of them except for the radio button one, it works!

For example, if I have this:

```
    $(function () {
        // set hidden form field with selected interviewee
        $('#interviewees').live("change", (function () {
            var selected = $("#interviewees").val();
            $("#selectedInterviewee").val(selected);
        }));
        // set hidden form field with selected timeslot
        $('input[name="timeslot"]').live("click", (function () {
            var valu = $(this).val();
            alert(valu);
            $("#selectedSlot").val(valu);
        }));
    });
```

then the radio button click event does NOT fire, though the first one (a dropdown list) does. But if I have the radio button one all by itself, it does. Any ideas????

The input tags look like this:

```
<input id="slot_7:30-AM" name="timeslot" type="radio" value="slot_7:30-AM" />
```

I am using IE 8 mostly, but I tried this on Firefox and the same thing happened. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And what does your html look like?

Comment: @David -- what other HTML (other than the input tag) do you need to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it to work by REVERSING the order of the event registrations:

```
    $(function () {
        // set hidden form field with selected timeslot
        $('input[name="timeslot"]').live("click", (function () {
            var valu = $(this).val();
            alert(valu);
            $("#selectedSlot").val(valu);
        }));
        // set hidden form field with selected interviewee
        $('#interviewees').live("change", (function () {
            var selected = $("#interviewees").val();
            $("#selectedInterviewee").val(selected);
        }));
    });
```

Ugh. I'm returning to my view that javascript is a flakey mess. But for whatever reason, it does work now. (Both of them work now ... very peculiar.)

Comment: attention: .live() is deprecated since version1.7 and was removed in jquery 1.9.  Use .on() to attach event handlers for now.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your html, I can't be totally sure, but I'm thinking the problem is the selector you're using:

```
$('input[name=["timeslot"]')
```

There are at least two problems that might cause issues:

1. the unclosed square-bracket, and
2. the use of square brackets inside the attribute selector. Try using: `$('input[name="timeslot"]')` instead.

---

**Edited** in response to comments to the answer, below.

The following seems to work:

```
$('input[name="timeslot"]').live('click', function() {
    var valu = $(this).val();
    alert(valu);
    $("#selectedSlot").val(valu);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QUqVs/).

I am, of course, using a `text` input, rather than a `hidden`, but since the selector works on the `id` it should work regardless of the `input` type.

Comment: I fixed the square bracket problem, but it still doesn't work (see my update). What do you mean about not seeing the HTML? I show the input tag in my post. What other HTML would you like to see?

Comment: @Cynthia: yeah, *very* weird...I'm currently experimenting, and I'll get back to you as soon as I work it out.